# Наша природа — наше достояние

Tags: пунктуация, тире, сказуемые, подлежащее

Нужно ли тире в данном случае между подлежащим и сказуемым?

Answer (score 1):

Да, тире между подлежащим и сказуемым необходимо.

Между подлежащим и именным сказуемым на месте отсутствующей связки ставится тире, **если подлежащее и сказуемое выражены существительными в форме именительного падежа:**

*Любовь – очарование природы...* (М. Зощенко. Голубая книга. Любовь)
Охрана природы – общее дело.
Живая природа – украшение земли.
Наш заповедник – национальное достояние.
[**Наша природа – наше достояние.**](http://blizko.by/notes/fotofakt-u-plakata-beregite-prirodu-v-voennom-gorodke-vedetsya-stroitelstvo)

[**Тире между членами предложения. §10**](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83_%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/)